# How to define onclick function with variables in it ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

I'm quite new in web development, I'm trying to create multiple buttons in a javascript function and define their onclick function in a for loop.

**What I want :**
When I click on the button, I want to recover the value associated with this button.

**What I have :**
When I click on any button, I am recovering the value associated with the last button.

I have made a simple example of what I'm trying to do :

HTML :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS :

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var i;
for (i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
  const root = document.createElement('button');
  root.setAttribute("class", "exerciceBox");
  root.textContent = i;
  root.onclick = function() {
    console.log(i);
  }
  document.getElementById("container").append(root);
}
```

I don't know if there is a best way to declare .onclick function for button created in JS files or maybe another way to do this.

I hope you could help me !
Thank you in advance,
Sincerely,
Valentin

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in **var** statement and it has scoping issue. The var statement declares a function-scoped or globally-scoped variable. To solve this declare the variable `i` by **let** statement to maintain the scope in for-loop.

A possible solution like below

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (let i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
  const root = document.createElement('button');
  root.setAttribute("class", "exerciceBox");
  root.textContent = i;
  root.onclick = function() {
    console.log(i);
  }
  document.getElementById("container").append(root);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a value attribute to your buttons here is how to do it :

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for (i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
  const root = document.createElement('button');
  root.setAttribute("class", "exerciceBox");
  // set the value of your button to i
  root.setAttribute("value", i);
  root.textContent = i;
  root.onclick = function() {
  // get the value using 'this' 
  console.log(this.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("container").append(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start at 0 in js.

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const root = document.createElement('button');
  root.setAttribute("class", "exerciceBox");
  root.textContent = i;
  root.onclick = function() {
    console.log(i++); // this prints out i (index) + 1
  }
  document.getElementById("container").append(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always getting the last value of i because the for increments it until the end of the loop, then, when you click the button, you see the incremented value.
Try this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const root = document.createElement('button');
    root.setAttribute("class", "exerciceBox");
    root.textContent = i;
    let thisButtonI = i; //Make a copy of the actual value of i
    root.onclick = function() {
        console.log(thisButtonI); //use the copy, not the original i
    }
    document.getElementById("container").append(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Don't create functions inside loops. It's bug prone since once the loop exits the function could be overridden exiting with the last loop values attached.
- Don't modify the DOM inside loops - such causes cluttering, unnecessary relayout and repaints

Here's a **better solution** on how to create a series of Elements given an array and insert them in the DOM

- Create a *blueprint* of your button (`EL_dataItem`) and assign the necessary attributes and event handlers
- Use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to *reduce* your `data` Array into a **DocumentFragment** collection.
- Use [`DocumentFragment API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and its `.append()` method
- Once the DocumentFragment is populated use [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) to insert the buttons where needed ***- all at once***.

```js
// Helpers
const ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);

// Your data Array
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Button Blueprint
const EL_dataItem = (item) => ELNew("button", {
  type:        "button",
  className:   "exerciceBox", // cice?..
  textContent: item,
  onclick()    { console.log(item); },
});

// Create all buttons (Append into DocumentFragment)
const DF_items = data.reduce((DF, item) => {
  DF.append(EL_dataItem(item));
  return DF;
}, new DocumentFragment());

// Append DocumentFragment once.
EL("#container").append(DF_items);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is that the value of variable `i` changes by the time the user gets to click on the buttons as you are referencing the variable directly in the `onlick` event handler.

```
root.onclick = function() {
    console.log(i);
}
```

You can replace the `onlick` handler and solve this issue by closure and IIFE.
This code will bind the value of `i` to the value when the loop is running by passing it as an argument and returning a function as the handler.

```
root.onclick = (function (i) {
    return function () {
      console.log(i);
      }; 
})(i);
```